# Can I use the same PvZ: Garden Warfare 2 account on my PC and Xbox One?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2

I want to play Garden Warfare 2 on my laptop. Can I use the same account as the one I use on my Xbox One?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you play PvZ2 for the first time you are asked to sign into your EA account. If you don't have an EA account you can make one. Assuming you did sign into your account on your Xbox, then when you play on your PC all you should have to do is sign into your EA account. 
Someone has asked a [similar question](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Bugs-Issues/Garden-warfare-2-Xbox-one-PC-transfer-help/td-p/5233276) on the EA discussion boards.

Comment: The link you provide is about cross-platform progress, though.